# OpenSSL, RVM, Brew, conflicting error

Tags: ruby, openssl, rvm

When I run ***brew doctor*** in Terminal:
I get the following error:

```
Warning: Some keg-only formula are linked into the Cellar.
You may wish to `brew unlink` these brews:

openssl
```

If I unlink it, and I type ***rvm requirements***:
I will get the following Error.

```
Checking requirements for osx.
dyld: Library not loaded: @@HOMEBREW_CELLAR@@/openssl/1.0.1f/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/openssl/bin/openssl
  Reason: image not found
Failed reading certificates path for '/usr/local/opt/openssl/bin/openssl' with return       code: ().
RVM autolibs is now configured with mode '2' => 'check and stop if missing',
please run `rvm autolibs enable` to let RVM do its job or run and read `rvm autolibs [help]`
or visit https://rvm.io/rvm/autolibs for more information.
Requirements installation failed with status: 133.
```

When I run brew unlink openssl, myssl version changed from OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
to OpenSSL 0.9.8y 5 Feb 2013

So the question is: How Do I make both Brew Doctor and RVM Requirements Happy ? By having the same OpeenSSL version ? (Assumptions)

Comment: nope! I heard macports confict homebrew, so I didn't install it

Comment: have you try `brew reinstall openssl`?

Comment: yup it works. openssl works fine. But its running version 0.9 instead of 1.0. That is the thing causing the issue.

Answer (score 74):

Try `brew reinstall openssl` then `brew link openssl --force`

Comment: Homebrew doesn't allow --force on this any more.

Answer (score 16):

Hengjie is half way there.

The problem is that OSX ships with a version of openssl in /usr/bin. Try this:

```
$ /usr/bin/openssl version
```

When homebrew installs openssl it will install it to /usr/local/Cellar/openssl, but by default it won't create the links because of the version conflict that it would create. To crete the links you need to type in:

```
$ brew link --force openssl
```

That will create symlinks to the brew version and you should be able to see the new version number by typing this:

```
$ /usr/local/bin/openssl version
```

There is one final problem. And that happens if your path variable has /usr/bin ahead of /usr/local/bin. Type this in:

```
$ echo $PATH
```

if you see /usr/bin ahead of /usr/local/bin then you need to update your .bash_profile to have something like this in it:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
```

That will mean that the new version will be used ahead of the old one.

Warning: the brew package says this "Mac OS X already provides this software and installing another version in parallel can cause all kinds of trouble."

So use at your own risk! I don't actually know what the "all kinds of trouble" is.

Comment: Brilliant reply, helped me a lot.

Comment: That works even on the latest Mac 10.10 Yosemite. Thanks

Comment: Doesn't force linking openssl go against best practice? https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/commit/b999edb3448793529aea8b29c01b3851bbc3b3eb

Comment: Newer homebrew started refusing to link `openssl` with `brew link --force`.  To fix this and force `rvm` to use the brew version of `openssl`, you need to set it on your `PATH` with:  `export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH"`

Put in `~/.bash_profile` to persist

Answer (score 5):

Had the same error on Mavericks just run "brew remove openssl" then "rvm install ruby"

RVM will install the correct version of OpenSSL now.

Answer (score 0):

or DO "which openssl" 
copy from that location to "/usr/local/opt/openssl/bin/openssl" . then try.
thing is "/usr/local/opt/openssl/bin/openssl" have old or corrupted certificate.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the key point to be aware of, I've copied and pasted into a text doc for later use.
Generally there are no consequences of this for you. If you build your
own software and it requires this formula, you'll need to add to your
build variables:

```
LDFLAGS:  -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib
CPPFLAGS: -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include
```

But does anyone think that this will have consequences for our macs in general?
Would a better alternative have been to force the link to the existing openssl? Or is it necessary to have the version from homebrew in order to correctly set up our Ruby development environments.
I'm keen to know, as I'm in the process of doing a lot of configuring with the intention of developing a website, and I want my development environment to be as stable as possible. 
I appreciate any of your responses, after a semester of unix and plenty of other research, there is still so much to know! But knowledge is power!

Answer (score 0):

Specifically for Mojave,

```
sudo installer -pkg /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg -target /`
```

from 
`https://gorails.com/setup/osx/10.14-mojave`