# Error when trying to install app with mysql2 gem

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, mysql2

Im trying to install an open source rails 3.2.21 application that uses the `mysql2` gem, but when i try and run the `bundle` commant I get the following error:

```
Fetching: mysql2-0.3.18.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
p
ERROR:  Error installing mysql2:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/my_username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20150614-72129-orqsb7.rb extconf.rb
checking for ruby/thread.h... yes
checking for rb_thread_call_without_gvl() in ruby/thread.h... yes
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes
checking for rb_hash_dup()... yes
checking for rb_intern3()... yes
-----
Using mysql_config at /usr/local/bin/mysql_config
-----
checking for mysql.h... yes
checking for errmsg.h... yes
checking for mysqld_error.h... yes
-----
Don't know how to set rpath on your system, if MySQL libraries are not in path mysql2 may not load
-----
-----
Setting libpath to /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.25/lib
-----
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean

make "DESTDIR="
compiling client.c
compiling infile.c
compiling mysql2_ext.c
compiling result.c
linking shared-object mysql2/mysql2.bundle
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/travis/.sm/pkg/active/lib'
ld: library not found for -lssl
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [mysql2.bundle] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/my_username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.18 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/my_username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/extensions/x86
```

I tried uninstalling every version of `mysql` I installed via homebrew and reinstalling them, like so:

```
brew uninstall --force mysql && brew install mysql
```

Then running:

```
sudo gem install mysql2
```

As suggested by a number of similar questions asked on here, but it still results in the same error as above.

Please could someone offer guidance on how to get this up and running?

Comment: try to run "brew doctor" and check if there are any errors. If so, follow the instructions and try again.

Comment: Have you installed gem's dependencies? https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2#general-instructions

Comment: @ValAsensio, I heartily disagree with you there, I think you should always try to use your production db in development, if possible. I never use sqlite in development, nor does anyone I work with.

Comment: @niels. Yes. I agree with this"I think you should always try to use your production db in development, " This ancient comment of mine was useless. I deleted it.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

The error log says:

```
ld: library not found for -lssl
```

So, you need to install `libssl`:

```
brew install openssl
```

---

As it was pointed out in comments, there might be a need to export the path to the library.

```
export LIBRARY_PATH=$LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/
```

Comment: That was not enough, One need to export it afterward like this:
`export LIBRARY_PATH=$LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/`

Comment: export LIBRARY_PATH=$LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/` Works for me after a long try. Thx!!

Comment: Why does Ruby suffer from this problem so much worse than any other ecosystems? Why do Gem developers not put effort into making good install processes?

Comment: @AndyRay This is absolutely not ruby to blame, but MacOS. This OS has never been suitable for development.

Answer (score 179):

For anybody still experiencing the issue:

When you install openssl via brew, you should get the following message:

> Apple has deprecated use of OpenSSL in favor of its own TLS and crypto libraries
>
> Generally there are no consequences of this for you. If you build your
>   own software and it requires this formula, you'll need to add to your
>   build variables:
>
> LDFLAGS:  -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib
>      CPPFLAGS: -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include
>      PKG_CONFIG_PATH: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/pkgconfig

You can set these build flags (for the local application) by running the following:

```
bundle config --local build.mysql2 "--with-ldflags=-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib --with-cppflags=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include"
```

This worked for me.

See [bundler's documentation](http://bundler.io/v1.13/man/bundle-config.1.html) for more information.

Comment: If you just want to use `gem install`, the following works:
  `gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.21' -- --with-ldflags=-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib --with-cppflags=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include`

Comment: ^^^ @niels that should be the answer... Alessandro's does not work on Sierra ("Warning: Refusing to link: open ssl..." --> something to do with the deprecated system of openssl)

Comment: @the12 niels's solution is for ``gem install``, mine is for ``bundle install``. What issue are you experiencing exactly, can you post the error? The solution I posted still works for me.

Comment: I started from trying to `bundle install` for a repo that depends on mysql. @AlessandroBerardi's solution did not work for me; @niels' did. :/

Comment: The bundle config command didn't work for me (although it has in the past). The 'gem install' command of niels did work (hours later). The bundle config command failed because it looks like it passed --with-ldflags and --with-cppflags as arguments to clang producing

clang: error: unsupported option '--with-cppflags=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include'

Comment: @the12 niels' comment is already an answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/55186244/5025116

Comment: --with-cppflags appears to break on latest OSX. I believe it can be omitted.`bundle config --local build.mysql2 "--with-ldflags=-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib"`

Comment: Yes just use the bundle config without the cppflags option and it works on big sir see xavier Shay's comment above

Answer (score 47):

Try this:

```
gem install mysql2 -v '0.5.2' -- --with-ldflags=-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib --with-cppflags=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include
```

(Update version as appropriate)

Comment: Given that the SSL library was not found this is the correct approach and worked fine for me.

Comment: First install `brew install openssl` then `gem install mysql2 -v '0.4.10' -- --with-ldflags=-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib --with-cppflags=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include
` worked for me, Thanks!

Comment: @TouseefMurtaza your answer worked for me - thank you!

Answer (score 36):

The solution for me was to install the Xcode Command Line Tools.

I had recently updated Xcode through the Mac App Store, and every time I do that, I've found that I have to reinstall the Command Line Tools again.

```
xcode-select --install
```

Answer (score 33):

Based on the solution [here](https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2/issues/795)

```
brew install openssl

export LIBRARY_PATH=$LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/
```

solved the problem.

Comment: the `export` really helps. even with existing openssl the path is missing.

Answer (score 18):

After Homebrew update (openssl@1.1) there is a new path for libs, so may use:

```
bundle config build.mysql2 --with-opt-dir=$(brew --prefix openssl)
bundle install
```

It will fix `ld: library not found for -lssl error`

Comment: This is the way.

Comment: Confirming that this works in December 2022, while the other answers are a bit outdated.

Answer (score 11):

Thanks @mudasobwa for pointing me in the right direction. It turns out the error was caused by an unlinked openssl file, so running:

```
brew reinstall openssl && brew link openssl --force
```

Solved the problem. I found the solution here: [OpenSSL, RVM, Brew, conflicting error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21508866/openssl-rvm-brew-conflicting-error)

Answer (score 11):

On MacBook air M1(macOS) it worked for me.

Install zstd

> brew install zstd

Install mysql2

> gem install mysql2 -v '0.5.3' -- --with-opt-dir=$(brew --prefix openssl) --with-ldflags=-L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/zstd/1.5.0/lib

Comment: This was the ONLY thing that worked for me on the M1 Mac Mini. Thank you for posting!

Comment: Thanks for this post!

Comment: This is the solution for Mac M1 pro

Answer (score 5):

This finally worked for me on macOS Monterey 12.3 (M1 Pro):

```
 gem install mysql2 -- --with-mysql-dir=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mysql/8.0.28_1
```

Make sure you read the [installation instructions](https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2#installing). Notable points for me were:

- Make sure MySQL is installed (`brew install mysql`)
- Make sure XCode select tools are installed (`xcode-select --install`)
- Set the `with-mysql-dir` option to wherever mysql was installed (check with `brew info mysql`)

Comment: I checked mysql folder name `ls /opt/homebrew/Cellar/mysql`, and found this folder `8.2.0_1`. So, I used this command `gem install mysql2 -- --with-mysql-dir=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mysql/8.2.0_1`. And it Worked! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo installer -pkg /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg -target /
```

From here:
https://gorails.com/setup/osx/10.14-mojave

Answer (score 2):

The combination of commands solved it me. I am on Mojave.

`brew reinstall openssl && brew link openssl --force`

and then

```
gem install mysql2 -v '0.4.10' -- \
  --with-ldflags=-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib \
  --with-cppflags=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include
```

Answer (score 2):

**Steps for me on Monterey M1 Mac**

```
brew install openssl@3

brew install zstd

gem install mysql2 -v '0.5.3' -- --with-opt-dir=$(brew --prefix openssl) --with-ldflags=-L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/zstd/1.5.0/lib

bundle config --local build.mysql2 "--with-opt-dir=$(brew --prefix openssl) --with-ldflags=-L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/zstd/1.5.0/lib"

bundle install
```

Comment: That third line to install `mysql2` generates this error on an M1 Mac w/ Monterey: `linking shared-object mysql2/mysql2.bundle
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/zstd/1.5.0/lib'
ld: library not found for -lzstd
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [mysql2.bundle] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/u/.gem/ruby/2.6.5/gems/mysql2-0.5.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/u/.gem/ruby/2.6.5/extensions/-darwin-21/2.6.0-static/mysql2-0.5.3/gem_make.out`

Comment: wonderful its work on Mac M1 chip..

Answer (score 1):

Seems that you miss the main files needed to build `mysql2` gem

```
sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev libmysqlclient-dev -y
```

`libsqlite3-dev` is not mandatory but install it since it's the default rails DB.

Answer (score 1):

Mac Catalina using Homebrew fix:
`gem install mysql2 -- --with-opt-dir="$(brew --prefix openssl)"`

Answer (score 1):

the following command works for my Mac os 12.1 MacOs Monterey

```
 gem install mysql2 -v '0.5.3' -- \
 --with-mysql-lib=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mysql/8.0.28/lib \
 --with-mysql-dir=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mysql/8.0.28 \
 --with-mysql-config=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mysql/8.0.28/bin/mysql_config \
 --with-mysql-include=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mysql/8.0.28/include
```

Please refer this link for more details
https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2/issues/1175

Answer (score 0):

I've been coding with mysql2 gem for years and have encountered with this issue time to time.

Today I found that this magic option `-- --with-ldflags=-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib --with-cppflags=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include` no longer worked on my Mac. Indeed, it looks like the default location where brew installs openssl has changed:

```
$ brew reinstall openssl

...

If you need to have openssl@3 first in your PATH, run:
  echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc

For compilers to find openssl@3 you may need to set:
  export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/lib"
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/include"
```

So following the message, I had to make a few changes to the command and got it work finally:

```
$ gem install mysql2 -v '0.5.3' -- --with-ldflags=-L/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/lib --with-cppflags=-I/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/include
```

Hope this will help someone!

Answer (score 0):

This helped me on MacOs 12.6 (Monterey)

```
brew install mysql openssl
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include"
gem install mysql2 -v '0.5.3' \
  --source 'https://rubygems.org/' -- \
  --with-cppflags=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include \
  --with-ldflags=-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib

bundle install
```

Thanks https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2/issues/1175#issuecomment-1069721834

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring implicit function declarations and linking zstd worked for me:

```
bundle config --global build.mysql2 '-- --with-cflags="-Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration" --with-ldflags=-L/opt/homebrew/opt/zstd/lib'
```

Answer (score -1):

I found that I had to use `--with-opt-dir=/usr/local/opt`.

Specifically, I added the following to my `~/.bundle/config` file:

```
BUNDLE_BUILD__MYSQL2: "--with-opt-dir=/usr/local/opt"
```