# Can't install mysql2 gem on macOS Sierra

Tags: mysql, ruby, macos, rubygems, macos-sierra

I'm setting up my development environment in the new **macOS Sierra** .

First of all, I installed **Rbenv**, **Ruby (2.3.1)**, **Homebrew** and so the latest version of **MySQL (5.7.15)**.

```
$ brew install mysql
$ mysql.server start
```

Ok, MySQL was initialized. Time to install the **mysql2** gem...

```
$ gem install mysql2 -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.15/bin/mysql_config
```

But it didn't work.

---

```
Building native extensions with: '--with-mysql-config=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.15/bin/mysql_config'
This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql2:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Users/macuser/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.4/ext/mysql2
/Users/macuser/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20160921-16853-x1boio.rb extconf.rb --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.15/bin/mysql_config
checking for ruby/thread.h... yes
checking for rb_thread_call_without_gvl() in ruby/thread.h... yes
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... no
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes
checking for rb_hash_dup()... yes
checking for rb_intern3()... yes
-----
Using mysql_config at /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.15/bin/mysql_config
-----
checking for mysql.h... yes
checking for errmsg.h... yes
checking for mysqld_error.h... yes
-----
Dont know how to set rpath on your system, if MySQL libraries are not in path mysql2 may not load
-----
-----
Setting libpath to /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.15/lib
-----
creating Makefile

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /Users/macuser/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-16/2.3.0-static/mysql2-0.4.4/mkmf.log

current directory: /Users/macuser/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.4/ext/mysql2
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: /Users/macuser/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.4/ext/mysql2
make "DESTDIR="
compiling client.c
compiling infile.c
compiling mysql2_ext.c
compiling result.c
compiling statement.c
linking shared-object mysql2/mysql2.bundle
ld: library not found for -lssl
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [mysql2.bundle] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/macuser/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.4 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/macuser/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-16/2.3.0-static/mysql2-0.4.4/gem_make.out
```

Comment: I wonder if this answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30834421/error-when-trying-to-install-app-with-mysql2-gem

Comment: Thanks, @spickermann. But it doesn't help me, same results after `brew install openssl`.

Comment: Did you also try `brew reinstall openssl && brew link openssl --force`

Comment: @spickermann This works for me!

Comment: https://qiita.com/tktcorporation/items/0ef8c930fc18ce72c301

Answer (score 103):

I just had the same problem, tried all of the solutions listed above, then commenced to bang my head against they keyboard for a couple of hours.

I then thought to try and install/reinstall the Xcode Command Line Tools:

```
xcode-select --install
```

Once I did that the mysql2 gem installed w/ no problems. I hope that does the trick!

Comment: I encountered the same problem after I update to MacOS Sierra 10.12.1  Thanks!

Comment: After doing this I got a different error: `Permission denied @ rb_sysopen`. That got fixed by using Sudo: `sudo bundle install`. Not an ideal solution, but hey, it worked!

Comment: On my 10.12.4 is just says `xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates`. Any other way to force reinstall?

Comment: @NicCottrell When running brew doctor I saw this message

Warning: A newer Command Line Tools release is available.
Update them from Software Update in System Preferences or run:
  softwareupdate --all --install --force

If that doesn't show you an update run:
  sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
  sudo xcode-select --install

Answer (score 68):

When you install openssl via brew, you should get the following message:

> Apple has deprecated use of OpenSSL in favor of its own TLS and crypto libraries
>
> Generally there are no consequences of this for you. If you build your
>   own software and it requires this formula, you'll need to add to your
>   build variables:
>
> LDFLAGS:  -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib
>      CPPFLAGS: -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include
>      PKG_CONFIG_PATH: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/pkgconfig

You can set these build flags (for the local application) by running the following:

```
bundle config --local build.mysql2 "--with-ldflags=-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib --with-cppflags=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include"
```

This worked for me.

See [bundler's documentation](http://bundler.io/v1.13/man/bundle-config.1.html) for more information.

Comment: This worked for me. It threw me "nil build" warning. I tried bundle install in next line, it worked for me. Thanks man.

Comment: Yeah works, thanks for saving me from banging my head for hours more

Comment: Thank god... Alessandro, Lady Gaga should do a song about you

Comment: I second that ^^

Comment: response after the command: `You are replacing the current local value of build.mysql2, which is currently nil`
running `bundle install` after this worked

Comment: Thanks. This works for me, without installing xcode.

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work for me on 10.15 Catalina. See Fed C's fix for what worked.

Comment: This worked for me, though I had to change to the paths to /usr/local/Cellar/openssl@3/3.0.0_1

Answer (score 24):

Lots of great answers, I was able to combine them into this:

```
gem install mysql2 --source 'https://rubygems.org/' -- --with-ldflags=-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib --with-cppflags=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include
```

because I was not comfortable with `bundle config`

Comment: Thank you! I was not comfortable `bundle config` either.

Answer (score 12):

I am here to share my fix, since the other answers didn't work.

For my environment, I need MySQL 5.6 so I had to use:

`brew install mysql56` instead of `brew install mysql`

Bundle installing the mysql2 gem kept failing, until:

`brew link mysql56`

I also ran afterwards:

`mysql.server start`

The last step might be unnecessary, but **just** in case.

Comment: Same worked with Percona, though I had to force it:
`brew link --force percona-server56`

Answer (score 9):

With Mac OS 10.15 Catalina when I tried Alessandro's fix the gem and extensions could be installed correctly but `bundle install` failed. What worked  was just:

```
bundle config --local build.mysql2 "--with-ldflags=-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib"
```

without the `cppflags` part.

Comment: The clue is provided in mkmf.log:
`clang: error: unsupported option '--with-cppflags=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include'`

Answer (score 5):

Here's what worked for me.

Originally I ran:

```
$ bundle config --local build.mysql2 "--with-ldflags=-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib --with-cppflags=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include"
```

then

```
$ bundle install
```

I received an error in  /Users/.../.bundle/ruby/2.5.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-18/2.5.0/mysql2-0.5.3/mkmf.log :

**clang: error: unsupported option '--with-cppflags=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include'**

So I removed *"--with-cppflags=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include"*

Then ran:

```
$ bundle config --local build.mysql2 "--with-ldflags=-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib"
```

followed by:

```
$ bundle install
```

Which worked.

Comment: This worked for someone I was helping who was on Sierra. My computer, which is on Mojave, worked with cppflags included, however.

Comment: I had to remove `.bundle/config` before re-running the bundle config w/o the `cppflags` but this solution worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Almost the same scenario as @Caio Tarifa, Ruby 2.3.3, mysql 5.6 and mysql2. Tried on couple of solutions above and finally make it work with @kylekeesling's approach.

First, tried on solution 1 by @spickermann:

```
brew reinstall openssl && brew link openssl --force
```

Nothing happened, same error shown.

Second, tried on solution by @Alessandro Berardi:

```
bundle config --local build.mysql2 "--with-ldflags=-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib --with-cppflags=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include"
```

This got different but more errors since it overwrite gem extension's config so all gem extension installation failed.

Finally, tried on @kylekeesling solution:

```
xcode-select --install
```

It fix mysql gem issue as well as nikogiri. Since I already intall Xcode, in my case it's reinstall the Xcode Command Line Tools.

Comment: Also ran the command **xcode-select --install** as well and that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing xcode-select --install

Comment: This solution works time-to-time. After 10.14 it refers to App Store.

Answer (score 1):

So I ran into this similar issue and for me it turned out to be a wrong ruby version and incompatible MySQL version.   I use ruby 2.3 on most of my projects but inherited a 2.1 project.  Changing to rvm to use 2.1 got me a little further.

Then I found this: https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2/issues/603 that said you had to use mysql2 gem version greater than 0.3.17 with MySQL version 5.7

Updated gem to 0.3.17 and it fired right up.   Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

If none of the above works .. like in my case, doing this solved the issue
`brew install openssl`

FYI: i am using MacOS Catalina

Answer (score 0):

So I tried everything here to no avail. Seems like a problem with ruby 2.6.0, I downgraded to 2.3.4p301 and everything worked fine (with `bundle config --local build.mysql2 "--with-ldflags=-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib --with-cppflags=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include"`)

Answer (score -2):

First, you should try 2 answer in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30834421/error-when-trying-to-install-app-with-mysql2-gem)
If you installed openssl but it still don't work. You should try to o refresh gems reference. A got the same issue and it worked for me.

`gem source -r https://rubygems.org/`

`gem source -a https://rubygems.org/`