# Cannot Install "mysql gem" on MacOS Sierra

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

I am trying to install the mysql2 gem for one of my rails projects but I am getting an error. I run this command:

```
gem install mysql2
```

The error says:

```
ld: library not found for -lssl
```

However when I run:

```
brew install openssl
```

I get (which proves that I have the -lssl library):

```
Error: openssl-1.0.2f already installed
To install this version, first `brew unlink openssl`
```

And alternatively when I run (which proves I have mysql on my machine):

```
brew install mysql
```

I get:

```
Error: mysql-5.7.10 already installed
To install this version, first `brew unlink mysql`
```

Very lost and would love to solve this, thank you in advance. I am running brew version 1.0.4.

Comment: try `brew doctor` ?

Comment: @BradJohnson thanks, I was able to get some hints from `brew doctor`, not a full solution though. See my answer below.

Comment: Reference this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39617761/cant-install-mysql2-gem-on-macos-sierra

Comment: Oh, yeah,maybe you need to rebrew mysql with those flags? Sorry, not a brew pro :)

Answer (score 2):

I am having the same problem on Mac OS Mojave.

The following worked for me. First – very important – I ran xcode and discovered it needed to install some crap again. Then I did

```
brew reinstall openssl 
gem install mysql2 -v '0.4.5' -- --with-ldflags=-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib --with-cppflags=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include
bundle install
```

The second line is based on the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51277007/failure-to-install-old-mysql2-gem).

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same issue on my MacOS Sierra by refreshing gems reference:

```
gem source -r https://rubygems.org/
gem source -a https://rubygems.org/
```