# Cannot install mysql2 gem for Rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mysql2

I've looked at and tried just about everything on the topic here at Stackoverflow.com and still can't figure this out...

When I 'gem install mysql2' I get a permissions error. when I 'sudo gem install mysql2' I get the following:

```
    Teds-MacBook-Pro:~ tedmartin$ sudo gem install mysql2
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql2:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Users/tedmartin/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.5/ext/mysql2
/Users/tedmartin/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20170420-50202-1nekuvd.rb extconf.rb
checking for rb_absint_size()... yes
checking for rb_absint_singlebit_p()... yes
checking for ruby/thread.h... yes
checking for rb_thread_call_without_gvl() in ruby/thread.h... yes
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... no
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes
checking for rb_hash_dup()... yes
checking for rb_intern3()... yes
checking for rb_big_cmp()... yes
-----
Using mysql_config at /usr/local/bin/mysql_config
-----
checking for mysql.h... yes
checking for SSL_MODE_DISABLED in mysql.h... yes
checking for SSL_MODE_PREFERRED in mysql.h... yes
checking for SSL_MODE_REQUIRED in mysql.h... yes
checking for SSL_MODE_VERIFY_CA in mysql.h... yes
checking for SSL_MODE_VERIFY_IDENTITY in mysql.h... yes
checking for errmsg.h... yes
checking for mysqld_error.h... yes
-----
Don't know how to set rpath on your system, if MySQL libraries are not in path mysql2 may not load
-----
-----
Setting libpath to /usr/local/Cellar/mysql-connector-c/6.1.9/lib
-----
creating Makefile

current directory: /Users/tedmartin/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.5/ext/mysql2
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: /Users/tedmartin/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.5/ext/mysql2
make "DESTDIR="
compiling client.c
compiling infile.c
compiling mysql2_ext.c
compiling result.c
compiling statement.c
linking shared-object mysql2/mysql2.bundle
ld: library not found for -l-lpthread
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [mysql2.bundle] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/tedmartin/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.5 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/tedmartin/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-15/2.4.0-static/mysql2-0.4.5/gem_make.out
```

Anyone who has an idea, suggestion, tip, fix, etc... I'd be really grateful.

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure why someone downvoted you.. have you installed mysql on your mac to begin with? Unlike other gems it's not just a case of bundle install, you can check by running mysql -u root from your terminal and seeing if it recognises the command. If not go to the mysql site and follow setup instructions for OSX

Comment: Thanks Mike. I've installed mysql both with Homebrew and downloading the community edition... I don't know why someone down voted me either... Oh well the joys of anonymous internetdom :)

Comment: C'est la vie! And what happens when you try to run mysql -u root from your terminal? Does it recognise the command?

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30834421/error-when-trying-to-install-app-with-mysql2-gem) @TedMartin.

Answer (score 43):

From the answer at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39617761/cant-install-mysql2-gem-on-macos-sierra#), running the following worked for me

`gem install mysql2 --source 'https://rubygems.org/' -- --with-ldflags=-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib --with-cppflags=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include`

Comment: This is the best answer for a one line solution

Answer (score 41):

I ran into this same issue on Mojave, and none of the previous answers worked for me but this commands mentioned in this Github issue [comment](https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2/issues/795#issuecomment-337006164) did

Step 1.

```
brew install openssl
```

Step 2.

```
export LIBRARY_PATH=$LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/
```

In my case I already had `openssl` installed so it was really the export command that solved the problem.

Comment: This was my issue as well. Had openssl, but needed the export. Thank you!

Answer (score 20):

1. Make sure openssl is installed on Mac via Homebrew.

```
brew install openssl
```

2. Install mysql2 gem.

```
gem install mysql2 -v '0.5.2' -- --with-ldflags=-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib --with-cppflags=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include
```

3. If the bug is not fixed, this above solution is the last one

```
sudo installer -pkg /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg -target /
```

Another solution if the above does not work.

```
cd /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2s/lib/

sudo cp libssl.1.0.0.dylib libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib /usr/local/lib
```

Comment: Only last solution works for me. And libssl.a, libcrypto.a should be also copied. Solution 2 helps to run gem install, but following bundle install still fail.

Answer (score 15):

This worked for me on macOS Catalina:

Make sure you have openssl installed.  If not:

```
brew install openssl
```

Then do the gem install:

```
gem install mysql2 -- --with-opt-dir="$(brew --prefix openssl)"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
which mysql
```

Then, use the output-result to install the gem using the existing mysql installation directory:

```
gem install mysql2 -- --with-mysql-dir=<mysql-installation-directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

It away working for me after 2h crazy

1. Unstall Ruby and Install Ruby v2.6.6
2. Run command line as Administrator `gem install mysql2`
3. Install rails `gem install rails`
4. Create new project `rails new my_proj -d mysql`

Work 100% in Windown