# mysql2 version 0.5.2 Installation Failed

Tags: ruby, openssl, rubygems, mysql2

I am trying to install mysql2 (version 0.5.2) on My MacBook running OSX 10.14.1 and using Rails 5.2.2. I have already installed it using gem *install mysql2* but it wasn't successful, yet it's in my gem file as:

```
gem 'mysql2'
```

When I try installing *gem mysql2*, I am getting the following error:

```
Fetching mysql2 0.5.2
Installing mysql2 0.5.2 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory:         /Users/lawrence/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/mysql2-    0.5.2/ext/mysql2
/Users/lawrence/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20181213-11829-    1fv4si0.rb extconf.rb
checking for rb_absint_size()... yes
checking for rb_absint_singlebit_p()... yes
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes
-----
Using mysql_config at /usr/local/bin/mysql_config
-----
checking for mysql.h... yes
checking for errmsg.h... yes
checking for SSL_MODE_DISABLED in mysql.h... yes
checking for SSL_MODE_PREFERRED in mysql.h... yes
checking for SSL_MODE_REQUIRED in mysql.h... yes
checking for SSL_MODE_VERIFY_CA in mysql.h... yes
checking for SSL_MODE_VERIFY_IDENTITY in mysql.h... yes
checking for MYSQL.net.vio in mysql.h... yes
checking for MYSQL.net.pvio in mysql.h... no
checking for MYSQL_ENABLE_CLEARTEXT_PLUGIN in mysql.h... yes
checking for SERVER_QUERY_NO_GOOD_INDEX_USED in mysql.h... yes
checking for SERVER_QUERY_NO_INDEX_USED in mysql.h... yes
checking for SERVER_QUERY_WAS_SLOW in mysql.h... yes
checking for MYSQL_OPTION_MULTI_STATEMENTS_ON in mysql.h... yes
checking for MYSQL_OPTION_MULTI_STATEMENTS_OFF in mysql.h... yes
checking for my_bool in mysql.h... no
-----
Don't know how to set rpath on your system, if MySQL libraries are not in     path mysql2 may not load
-----
-----
Setting libpath to /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.12/lib
-----
creating Makefile

current directory:     /Users/lawrence/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/mysql2-    0.5.2/ext/mysql2
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory:     /Users/lawrence/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/mysql2-0.5.2/ext/mysql2
make "DESTDIR="
compiling client.c
compiling infile.c
compiling mysql2_ext.c
compiling result.c
compiling statement.c
linking shared-object mysql2/mysql2.bundle
ld: library not found for -lssl
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [mysql2.bundle] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in     /Users/lawrence/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/mysql2-0.5.2 for inspection.
Results logged to     /Users/lawrence/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/extensions/x86_64-    darwin-18/2.5.0-static/mysql2-0.5.2/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing mysql2 (0.5.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install mysql2 -v '0.5.2' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile: mysql2
```

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have found the Answer

Mojave changed the location of header files necessary for compiling C extensions. You might need to run the following command to install pg, mysql2, nokogiri, or other gems that require C extensions:

```
sudo installer -pkg /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg -target /
```

Follow the link below and find out more.

https://gorails.com/setup/osx/10.14-mojave

Comment: There needs to be a space after "-pkg" for this to work. Thank you for including the source link so I could figure that out. Upvoted because despite error this solved my problem.

Comment: I've edited to add the space. Thanks for this answer which is literally the only thing that worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

`ld: library not found for -lssl` is the likely culprit.

Try `brew install openssl`. Also, check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30834421/error-when-trying-to-install-app-with-mysql2-gem) for more information.

EDIT: For future users this worked for me facing a similar issue.  Make sure you change the -v to whatever version you need. I am on rails 4.2.x so used `0.4.10`, Rails 5.x would use `0.5.x`.

`gem install mysql2 -v '0.4.10' -- --with-ldflags=-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib --with-cppflags=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include`

Comment: This didn't solve my problem. am still looking for a solution.

Comment: `/usr/local/opt` path is not present in "OS X Big Sur", alternatively, installing OpenSSL with home-brew places it `/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/bin/openssl`